# Find all numbers in a range with decimals

Tags: php, math

I have the following function that I wrote

```
 function range_gen($num1,$num2){


    $exp = explode('.',$num1);

    $accuracy = strlen($exp[1]);

    $dp = array(
    0=>1,
    1=>0.1,
    2=>0.01,
    3=>0.001,
    4=>0.0001);


    foreach ($dp as $key=>$acc)
    {
      if ($accuracy ==$key){
        $step = $acc;
      }
    }


      foreach (range($num1, $num2 ,$step) as $number) {
          $ans.= "\"".$number."\",";
      }
        echo trim($ans,",");
    }
```

If I give it two values eg 20.49 and 20.51 then the result is 20.49,20.5,20.51

How can I get the  20.5 to be 20.50?

Thanks
Rob

Comment: Oh, my, we need a reference question for this. Floating point numbers are not exact, especially not if the denominator of the number you want to express is not a power of 2. But that's not your biggest problem: The *rationale* of the function is flawed. What should it output for the inputs `(0, 0.23)`? What for `(0.000000001, 0.000000004)` (it currently crashes spectacularly), `(-2e-18, -3e-18)`, or `(1/3, 2/3)`?

Comment: How would you write it? I know its crude but for my purpose this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't "get" 20.5 because php will automatically truncate trailing decimal 0's. But, when you print the number with `echo`, you can format it:

```
echo number_format($number, 2);
```

In your loop, this could be done like this:

You can have something like this:

```
foreach (range($num1, $num2 ,$step) as $number) {
      $ans.= "\"".number_format($number,2)."\",";
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

### Options

#### number_format()

This is the domain of the PHP [`number_format()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/number_format) function.

```
echo number_format($number, 2);
```

Example using your loop code:

```
foreach (range($num1, $num2 ,$step) as $number) {
    $ans .= '"' . number_format($number,2) . '",';
}
```

#### sprintf()

Another option is to use [`sprintf()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
echo sprintf("%.2f", $number);
```

Example using your loop code:

```
foreach (range($num1, $num2 ,$step) as $number) {
    $ans .= '"' . sprintf("%.2f", $number) . '",';
}
```

### How I would do it

```
foreach (range($num1, $num2 ,$step) as $number) {
    $ans[] = number_format($number,2);
}
$ans = '"' . implode('", "', $ans) . '"';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take look at the [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) function.

Example:
`$formatted = sprintf('%.2f', 2.5);`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [sprintf function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) like this:

```
$x=20.5;
$str = sprintf("%.2f", $x);
var_dump($str);
```

**OUTPUT:**

string(5) "20.50"